# Spring JPA: How to get dependencies right with injection?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

My data model consists of three objects, let's call them `A`, `B` and `C`. `A` has a one-to-many relationship to `B`, and `B` to `C`. They are only modeled as interfaces.

To get concrete versions of them, I have interfaces `AProvider`, `BProvider` and `CProvider` which provide create, retrieve, and delete operations.

I am now doing an implementation using Spring-JPA and Hibernate by the means of `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`. For this, I have three `@Entity`s `InternalA`, `InternalB` and `InternalC` which do not implement the `A`, `B` and `C` interfaces, but are used as transfer objects only. To access them, I use the autogenerated repositories from Spring (see `CrudRepository`).

For creating the "real" objects, I have implementations of the `XProvider` interfaces which inject their necessary dependencies. This structure is the following (I prefer `javax.inject` style injection):

```
@Component
public class AProviderImpl implements AProvider {

    @Inject
    private InternalARepository _aRepository;

    // implementation
}

@Component
public class BProviderImpl implements BProvider {

    @Inject
    private InternalBRepository _bRepository;

    @Inject
    private AProvider _aProvider;

    // implementation
}

@Component
public class CProviderImpl implements CProvider {

    @Inject
    private InternalCRepository _cRepository;

    @Inject
    private BProvider _bProvider;

    // implementation
}
```

I figure out that this should work, and the `AutowireCapableBeanFactory` correctly figures out what to instantiate first. But this only works up to the `BProviderImpl`, e.g., when removing the `CProviderImpl`. As soon as `CProviderImpl` exists, initialization fails with `No qualifying bean of type [com.somewhere.BProvider] found`.

It makes no difference if I use `@Autowired` instead of `@Inject`.

I stepped through the initialization process with a debugger and the `CProvider` is indeed initialized first, i.e., the bean factory does not correctly figure out that it needs the `BProvider` which in turn needs the `AProvider` first.

My current workaround is using `@DependsOn` like this:

```
@Component("myAProvider")
public class AProviderImpl implements AProvider { ... }

@Component("myBProvider")
@DependsOn("myAProvider")
public class BProviderImpl implements BProvider { ... }

@Component("myCProvider")
@DependsOn("myBProvider")
public class CProviderImpl implements CProvider { ... }
```

This works, but I read elsewhere that this is a code smell and should be avoided because it introduces implicit dependencies. Currently, this is all local to one module, so it is no problem there, but later my model will grow and I will have model elements and providers spread over multiple modules, so I cannot use `@DependsOn` until kingdom come.

Is there a better way to tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@Order` annotation, this will enable to prioritize Bean loading and doesn't pollute your loading hierarchy as with `@DependsOn`. With this you can certainly modularize your design later without a problem. Lowest order value has highest priority.

```
@Component("myAProvider")
@Order(1)
public class AProviderImpl implements AProvider { ... }

@Component("myBProvider")
@Order(2)
public class BProviderImpl implements BProvider { ... }

@Component("myCProvider")
@Order(3)
public class CProviderImpl implements CProvider { ... }
```

Comment: I just tried this and it did not work. I get the "No qualifying bean" exception. I found that using `@Lazy` seems to do the trick. This way, the beans are initialized in the order the bean factory thinks it must use, but all injected stuff is initialized the first time it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I found another workaround: Lazy initialization. Since initialization of my `XProvider`s are not long-running, I just added the `@Lazy` annotation. That way, Spring creates uninitialized instances and adds them to the registry, and when at a later point an injected dependency is accessed, it is initialized.

I don't know if this is the best solution, but I think it is better than using `@DependsOn` and it should be working over module boundaries.